(Pinescript question) Ignore first encountered short entry and enter next long entry. Is there a way?
In TradingView, I've integrated TradingView with Binance using alertMessage pinescript function. when Buying or selling condition is met, TradingView fires the signal to binance to place buy or sell order through alertmessage function automatically. The problem is that I only want to enter first met long and close at next short since the strategy I use is for the spot trading. not for the futures market.
So is there a way to ignore first encountered short entry and enter the next encountered long entry?

The alertMessege funcion works fine, the problem is I frequently miss long entry opportunities and if I turn on Alert when long position has already been placed in TradingView and when the next short entry condition is met, entered and is signaled to binance, My trade will enter short position when what I really want is to enter long position when first long condition is met.
It's very difficult to keep an eye on my phone all day and turn on Alert when previous long position is closed(entered short position) to wait for the next long entry.
Is there a way to enter first met long entry automatically ignoring the first encountered short entry?
I've been trying to watch my phone all day to turn on Alert when my long position is closed(short position is entered) for the next long entry opportunity. But It's very difficult. Every time I look at my phone, it's already been entered long position. I tried to send a alert message to my phone to notify me when short position is entered but Is there an easier way? like turning on alert anytime and the long position is placed automatically ignoring the first encountered short entry?
